# If statement in multiple function call

Tags: php

Is there any way to create an if-statement in a multiple function call in PHP?

I am looking for something like this:

```
$object = new Object::method1('a')
    ->method1('b')
    if($someVar == 'c') { ->method1('c') } // <- This is what I am looking for
    ->method2();

$object->method3();
```

The method order is fixed!

I tried something like this, but it isn't working, because `method2()` must be called in the same statement, otherwise it doesn't find `method3()`.

```
$object = new Object::method1('a')
    ->method1('b');

if($someVar == 'c') {
   $object->method1('c');
}

$object->method2();
$object->method3();
```

*EDIT:*
My orginal code is a very complex SQL query (tried to create a MCVE). `method1` is used to add where clauses, `method3()` will query the result.

Comment: Create a method that will return a method if the condition is met

Comment: You can create an empty method that does nothing but `return $this;` and call it like so: `$instance->method1()->{$bool ? 'method2' : 'blank'}()->method3();` - [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/893030)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your methods return an object that contains the next method. So you need to execute the methods on the return values of the previous methods:

```
$object = new Object::method1('a')
        ->method1('b');

if($someVar == 'c') {
    $object = $object->method1('c');
}

$object = $object->method2();
$object->method3();
```

It would be nicer to have logical variable names, but you can use this to check if it works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I tried to create a minimal working example but it sounds like it is so minimal - sorry for that! I will edit my question to make it more clear for the future googlers who will find this question ;-)